# How to write file with bash script that has " and ' in the line?

Tags: bash, scripting

Trying to use Linux bash script to write to a file but unable to write the below line because of the extra
" and ' symbols in the line. Is there a better way to write a file with linux bash script or a way that will work?

```
echo "add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' https://*.jsdelivr.n$ >> $file
```

I'm a noob to bash scripting and appreciate the help.

Comment: Simply escape that characters with a `\ `.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this.  A heredoc is a good choice:

```
cat >> $file << \EOF
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' https://*.jsdelivr.n$
EOF
```

This simply takes everything until the EOF verbatim as input to cat, and writes it to the file.  (It's not clear to me if you want a double quote before `add_header`; if so, prepend it.) Another reasonable alternative is to escape double quotes in a double quoted string:

```
echo "add_header Content-Security-Policy \"default-src 'self' https://*.jsdelivr.n$" >> $file
```